# What is the justification for this equivalence: $ \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} |x(m - n)|= \|x\|_1 $

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

In Berberian's Lectures in Functional Analysis and Operator Theory, I'm having trouble following the Aperitif on Wiener's Theorem and some of lapses in logic present within; one in particular.

On the proof of the convergence of  $ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x(m - n)y(n) $, the author asserts the following equivalence:

$ \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} x(m - n) = \|x\|_1 $ - note the change in index.

Given that x $ \in  l^1(\mathbb{Z}) $  for $ x = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x(n) e_n $

where $e_n (m) = \delta_{mn}$

and $(xy)(m)= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x(m - n)y(n) $ for $ m \in \mathbb{z}$

Why does $ \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} |x(m - n)|$ = $\|x\|_1$ ?

Why does a "one" just magically appear as a subscript?

Note on edits: I had $y(n)$ originally multiplied to the sum, but that was not what I was intending to ask about; my apologies.

Comment: Is that a typo in the title: $\|x_1\|$ versus $\|x\|_1?$

Comment: What is $y$? If $y(n)=0$ and $x\neq 0$, then the LHS is $0$ while the RHS is not (assuming $\|\cdot\|_1$ is the $\ell^1$ norm).

Comment: Are you sure it's not $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x(m-n) y(n)$, i.e. the convolution of $x$ with $y$? Because as written you just have $y(n) \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty x(m)$ which is not guaranteed to be $\| x \|_1$ at all. As for the convolution of $x$ with $y$, a relation like this obviously depends on a good choice of $y$...

Comment: @AdrianKeister it is indeed a typo, in fact, there is another more egregious typo which changed what I was intending to ask; allow me to remedy that momentarily.

Comment: You need to repace $x(m-n)$ with $|x(m-n)|$, otherwise the equality is false if $x$ has strictly negative terms.

Comment: @LorenzoQuarisa True, true; edited.

Comment: Well, now the equality is reduced to proving that $\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}|x(m-n)|=\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}|x(m)|$.

Answer (score 1):

"Why does a "one" just magically appear as a subscript?"  It's the definition of the $\ell^{1}(\mathbb{Z})$-norm.  Given a sequence $a : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{C}$, we define the norm $\|\cdot\|_{1}$ by 
\begin{equation*}
\|a\|_{1} = \sum_{n = - \infty}^{\infty} |a(n)|.
\end{equation*}
Of course, this is only a norm on the vector space of sequences for which the sum is finite.  This is precisely the definition of the Banach space $\ell^{1}(\mathbb{Z})$.

Now given a sequence $x : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{C}$ and an integer $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, substitution implies that 
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{m = - \infty}^{\infty} |x(m - n)| = \sum_{m = - \infty}^{\infty} |x(m)| = \|x\|_{1}.
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 0):

In case we are talking about numbers, clearly
$$
\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} |x(m - n)y(n)| = \|x\|_1y(n),
$$
as it must be in the book (it cannot be as you wrote).

Comment: Yeah my bad I realized I made a typo which carried through and morphed my intended question into what you have written. 

My confusion lies in this: $ \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} |x(m - n)|= ||{x}_1|| $ I don't get why that equals that.

Comment: It is just a translation by $n$.

Comment: Oh wowwwww so it's pretty much just shifting each member of the sequence in the space? Of course that wouldn't affect their magnitude and thus the magnitude of their sums. Thank you very much!